# How to perform Case insensitive Equality operation using EF Core 6.0 and PostgresSql

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, collation, ef-core-6.0

I am upgrading a web app from Asp.Net Core 2.0 to .Net 6. This application uses Entity Framework Core 6 and PostgreSQL 12 DB. Application has a context class named ApplicationDbContext which is setup in following manner.

Setup -

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(
               new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(App.Constants.PostgresConnectionString),
               (opts) => { opts.MigrationsAssembly(_migrationsAssembly); opts.CommandTimeout(COMMAND_TIMEOUT); }),
               ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Upon using Equals() method overload with StringComparison parameter to perform equality check an exception is raised stating the operation could not be translated, e.g.

```
_dbContext.Users.Any(t => t.Email.Equals(user.Email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

I found that case insensitive search is not supported on EF Core 6.0 and its left up to DB collation, I found alternative approaches to achieve the required outcome here
([EF Core postgresql string compare (case-insensitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084881/ef-core-postgresql-string-compare-case-insensitive)). However apart from setting up collation on database, other options are not feasible to the current use case.

In order to setup collation on the database I modified my context class using this documentation (https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc/collations-and-case-sensitivity.html?tabs=data-annotations), which turned my context class to look like this -

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.HasCollation("case_insensitive_collation", locale: "en-u-ks-primary", provider: "icu", deterministic: false);
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        
        protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
        {
            configurationBuilder.Properties<string>().UseCollation("case_insensitive_collation");
        }
}
```

and the corresponding db code was modified to -

```
_dbContext.Users.Any(t => t.Email.Equals(user.Email))
```

After performing these modifications in code to setup case insensitive collation, the database is still performing case sensitive equality comparison. i.e. it does not distinguish between user email abc@company.com and ABC@company.com.

I have following queries -

1. Am I setting up collation incorrectly?
2. How can I achieve case insensitive equality/search with this setup (without creating a new db/indexes)?

Note - The database already exists, additionally it's not feasible to recreate the db/indexes.

Comment: So you have an existing database and then change collation in the context? If so, it looks like migrations ignore that, I guess because, just as in Sql Server, changing collations in the db schema is not trivial.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an EF issue that can be fixed in the DbContext, it is a data schema issue. If the PostgreSQL schema is set up with a CS collation, all string comparisons will be case sensitive. There are Case Insensitive data types (citext) and indexing options to index strings as lower or upper case, but I'm not sure how well these might be supported by EF and they require schema changes. This typically means in the design of anything responsible for inserting data that might be treated case insensitive would be to always ToLower/ToUpper all inserts and comparisons.

Comment: @GertArnold that might be the case, I would dig into the logs to see if anything is going wrong there. Alternatively, can you help me setup this approach [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity#explicit-collation-in-a-query). The article refers to a collation "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" in SQL Server and I'm unsure what the equivalent to that would be in PostgreSql and how to use that. TIA

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16) is an explanation of the abbreviations in Sql Server collations.