# EF Core contains case sensitive query

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a project where I use Entity Framework Core and PostgreSQL. In this project, I want to query for string types with case insensitivity. How can I do that?

Here is my `DbContext` methods:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasCollation("my_collation", locale: "en-u-ks-primary", provider: "icu", deterministic: true);
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    SeedDatabase(modelBuilder);
}

protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Properties<string>().UseCollation("my_collation");
}
```

Here are my query samples:

```
var b = await _uow.SysHistoryRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.TableName.Contains("Sirket"));
var a = await _uow.SysHistoryRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.TableName.Contains("sirket"));
```

It works in the like query in PostgresSql, but I get the error I specified in EF Core.

The error message that is returned while querying:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '0A000: nondeterministic collations are not supported for substring searches'

Comment: Not specific to EF core but maybe it helps -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266097/postgresql-nondeterministic-collations-are-not-supported-for-like

Comment: Might be duplicate -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084881/ef-core-postgresql-string-compare-case-insensitive